# SAFARI zooming screen issue

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, zooming, viewport

i have included view-port meta tag in header i.e.

```
<meta name="view-port" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```

but in iPhone screen..its allow user to zoom screen using pinch in/pinch out.

Comment: Try adding user-scalable=no.

Comment: Sorry, I see my answer was not a good idea.  Look at this blog http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
  if (event.touches.length > 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
```